# How to get range between two dates in millisecond in php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How to get a range between two dates in a millisecond :

I have an example of the correct answer:

```
time_start = 2018-12-18 12:33:53.1231;

time_end = 2018-12-18 12:34:10.1523;

result = 17.0292;
```

> **what I'm asking is, what is the formula for calculating it?**

I have tried some code but the result is `16.708`

```
$dt_start = 2018-12-18 12:33:53.1231;
$dt_end = 2018-12-18 12:34:10.1523;

            $ex_start = explode(".",$dt_start);
            $ex_end = explode(".",$dt_end);
            $datetime_start = strtotime($ex_start[0]);
            $datetime_end = strtotime($ex_end[0]);
            $total_detik = $datetime_end-$datetime_start;
                // dd($ex_end[0]);
            $milis_start = floatval($ex_start[1]);
            $milis_end = floatval($ex_end[1]);
            $range_milis = $milis_start-$milis_end;
            $new_range_milis = $range_milis/10000;
                // dd($range_milis);
            $second = $datetime_end-$datetime_start+$range_milis/10000;
            dd($second);
```

//output '16.708'

Comment: you should show your code inside your question as text, not as an image

Comment: if you are using laravel you SHOULD know it uses CARBON and just open carbon website and search for range between two dates.then converst to ms

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715247/how-to-get-time-difference-in-milliseconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to find the difference between two time.

```
<?php
function calculateTransactionDuration($startDate, $endDate)
{
    $startDateFormat = new DateTime($startDate);
    $EndDateFormat = new DateTime($endDate);
    $uDiff = ($startDateFormat->format('u') - $EndDateFormat->format('u')) / (1000 * 1000);;
    $diff = $startDateFormat->diff($EndDateFormat);
    $s = (int) $diff->format('%s') - $uDiff;
    $i = (int) ($diff->format('%i')) * 60; 
    $h = (int) ($diff->format('%h')) * 60 * 60; 

    return sprintf('%.6f', abs($h + $i + $s)); 
}
$time_start = '2018-12-18 12:33:53.1231';

$time_end = '2018-12-18 12:34:10.1523';

echo $difference = calculateTransactionDuration($time_start, $time_end); 
// output = 17.029200
```